# c# interop excel, Change the "After pressing Enter, move selection" option

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Change the Direction to 'non' on "After pressing Enter, move selection" 
like this http://prntscr.com/hy0azf

but in the code

I did not find any way to do it...
And my English is not that good and I did not find it on google...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `MoveAfterReturn` property of Excel Application to `false` as in `.MoveAfterReturn = false;`